# $\int {3\over 2t+100}\;dt$ has two solutions

Tags: integration

The integral 
$$\int {3\over 2t+100}\;dt$$
has two solutions, why is that?

Some websites show that the answer is ${3\over 2} ln(t+50)$ while other websites show that the answer is ${3\over 2} ln(2t+100)$. If I plot it, the graphs aren't the same.

They all use u-sub with $u=2t+100$ or with $u=t+50$ which give different answers, and it confuses me.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't realize that.

Comment: The plots are the same, to a vertical translation.

Comment: Neither is correct... Antiderivatives are $$\tfrac32\ln|t+50|+C$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\log(2t+100)=\log(t+50)+\log2$ -- so the difference between the two antiderivatives is just a constant of integration.

Remember that antiderivatives are only unique up to an arbitrary constant term.

Comment: Remember the ${}+C$ when doing indefinite integrals. This is what it's for.